# Sqlite3 relational database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect the id in the user class to the user_id in task class. I read the documentation from sqlalchemy and I have a hard time understanding the db.relationship part. I have also encountered a problem when updating the tables, when I ran db.create_all() in the terminal, these classes wasn't updated (it previously worked). Is this because the relational database I set up was wrong?

Here is my classes

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(80), nullable=False)

class Task(db.Model): 
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.Text)
    complete =db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
```

And here is the documentation example

```
class Category(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))

# Post table (in app/models/post.py)
class Post(db.Model, CRUDMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(80))
    body = db.Column(db.Text)
    pub_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)

    # One to many relationship
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = db.relationship('Category', backref=db.backref('posts'))
```

Any answers or opinions will be greatly appreciated, thankyou.

Comment: Relationships are a way of expressing rows in related tables as attributes of a model, for example `Category.posts` will contain all the `Post` instances that relate to a given category.  `create_all` will create non-existent tables, but it won;t update existing tables.  For that you need a tool like flask-migrate (or you can just delete your tables, if you don't care about the data).

Comment: Oooh I see, thankyou so much. Do you know anyway to delete the tables? And by your explanation does that mean relationship aren't necessary? Or if it is necessary, what will my relationship look like? If you want, you can answer this in the answer section so I can mark it as correct.

Comment: [db.drop_all](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.drop_all).  [Relationships](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#one-to-many-relationships) are a convenience, not a necessity.  If you want to find a category's posts you can query the database for them if there is no relationship.